# Trigger download when a click event is pressed for angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following icon that has a click event

```
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let history of exportHistory">
        <md-icon  (click)="onDownloadClick(history)" md-list-avatar>file_download</md-icon>
        <a md-line>{{history.exportDate_epoch | epoch | date:'mediumDate'}}</a>
        <p md-line> Exported by: {{history.by}}</p>
        <p md-line> {{history.numberOfEntries}} Entries</p>
    </md-list-item>
```

My history object has a property 'url' that contains the download link.

So when I do the following I get the download link.

```
onDownloadClick(history: ExportHistoryModel) {
    console.log(history.url);
}
```

How can I trigger the file download just as if I pressed a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can try several approaches as stated in that [Blog](https://pixelscommander.com/javascript/javascript-file-download-ignore-content-type/).

Best one would be to programmatically create an `<a>` tag with the "download" HTML5 attribute.

```
const url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/130px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png';
$('<a />')
  .attr('href',url)
  .attr('download', 'YourFileName.png')
  [0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the attributes of `md-icon` but you can simply wrap it in an anchor tag:

```
<md-list-item *ngFor="let history of exportHistory">
    <a href="{{history.url}}"><md-icon  (click)="onDownloadClick(history)" md-list-avatar>file_download</md-icon></a>
    <a md-line>{{history.exportDate_epoch | epoch | date:'mediumDate'}}</a>
    <p md-line> Exported by: {{history.by}}</p>
    <p md-line> {{history.numberOfEntries}} Entries</p>
</md-list-item>
```